# Reverse print an array in assembly programming

Tags: arrays, assembly, reverse

I need to reverse print a string array in assembly language. Following is my code.

```
proc reverseAr
    mov cl,count
    mov si,offset Ar
    mov si,3
    write2:

        mov dl,Ar[si]
        mov ah,02h
        int 21h
        dec si
    loop write2
ret
endp
```

But this doesnot give the answer. Can anybody tell me what is the exact meaning of si? Is it not the index of the array position?

Comment: In a segmented memory model (which your program seems intended to run in), `offset AR` would give you the 16-bit offset of `Ar` within the segment where `Ar` is located. If you then read from `[si]` you'd be reading from `[ds:si]`, i.e. the from the offset specified by `si` in the segment specified by `ds`. By the way, `loop` decrements `cx`, not just `cl`. So you should use `movzx cx,byte ptr count` instead of `mov cl,count`.

Comment: One issue is that right after you wrote the address of the array `Ar` into `si`, you overwrote it with a `3`. That probably wasn't your intention. You want to add the length of the array to `si` after you load the base address of the array there. I'm assuming everything is within the segment pointed to by `ds` in this case. If it isn't, then it gets slightly more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
proc reverseArray
    mov cl,count
    dec cl
    dec si
    printRevArr:
        mov dl,arr[si]
        add dl,48
        mov ah,02h
        int 21h

        dec si

    loop printRevArr

    ret
endp
```

Do not use `mov si,offset Ar` .It will reset the array indexes.

Answer (score 1):

si means source index register.
It can be used as pointer.
it is Offset Register
syntax will be:

SI  Source index        : General addressing, source offset in string ops