# how can l changed this solution?

Tags: string, assembly, x86, reverse

```
org 100h

jmp var1       ; jump over data declaration

source db 'This is the source string',0
target db SIZEOF source DUP ('#')


var1:
Mov   SI,25;lenght of the string
start:  

Mov  AL,source[SI]
DEC SI    

Mov  ah ,0eh
int 10h   
mov BL,target[DI]

CMP source[SI],BL;comparing to get the end of the string
je stop

jmp start                     

stop:
mov     ah, 0 
      ; wait for any key....
ret ; return to operating system.
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, thank you for posting your first question. For the best possible answers questions should be clear about what you are trying to achieve and what you have done to get to where you are now. There is a [great article about how to write good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), please consider reading it and editing your question to be clearer about what you want.

Comment: l dont want to smile or another symbol in program

Comment: Magic eight ball tells me that you're trying to figure out why your code continues writing after the end of the string.

Comment: .....   21h    ; wait for any key....
ret ; return to operating system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse print an array in assembly programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493133/reverse-print-an-array-in-assembly-programming)

Answer (score 1):

Let's take this a piece at a time...

We're off to a good start:

```
org 100h

jmp var1       ; jump over data declaration

source db 'This is the source string',0
target db SIZEOF source DUP ('#')


var1:
Mov   SI,25;lenght of the string
start:  

Mov  AL,source[SI]
DEC SI    

Mov  ah ,0eh
int 10h   
mov BL,target[DI]
```

Here we find our first problem. You never set DI to anything. DI could have absolutely any value at all. Since this is the all-too-familiar "reverse a string in assembly" assignment, I shall not solve it for you.

```
CMP source[SI],BL;comparing to get the end of the string
```

How does this check for the end of the string??  Your major problem is right here.  You have source[26] (or so) set to a zero. Shouldn't you be checking to see if `source[SI]` is equal to zero?

```
je stop

jmp start
```

So, please take this answer as a freebie in debugging. I am still voting to close this as a duplicate, however! :)